# Bootstrap nav pills active class bug when scrolling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I scroll to a certain section of my webpage, that specific nav pill section will light up, as shown:

[image]

It works just as expected for when I scroll to Home and Resume. However, when I click on, let's say Resume, and then scroll - observe what happens when I scroll down to Contact:

[image]

Now both Resume and Contact are highlighted. When I take this piece of code away, it works as expected. The first part is for smooth transition scrolling (when clicked), and the second part is for scrolling, both written in jQuery.

```
//Smooth transition scroll when nav pill is clicked
//When I take this code out, it works fine
var anchor = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function(){
    $(anchor).animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

//Change active class when scrolling
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (position <= home.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position >= home.top) {
        $('.home-class').addClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > resume.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').addClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > contact.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

If someone can point out what's going on, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you use [Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)?

Comment: Again, the issue persists in the way I had written the anchor transition function. Everything works fine if I took out the anchor function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical problem. You should compare position with larger top position first.

for example If resume.top is 500, contact.top is 700, position is 750..

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (position <= home.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position >= home.top) {
        $('.home-class').addClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }
    /* .resume-class will have active class because 701 > 500 */
    if (position > resume.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').addClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    /* .contact-class will have active class too because 701 > 700 */
    if (position > contact.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

So you need to change your code like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (position >= contact.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').addClass('active');
        return;
    }

    if (position >= resume.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').addClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
        return;
    }

    if (position >= home.top) {
        $('.home-class').addClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
        return;
    }

    if (position < home.top) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I don't see why that's an issue. Your solution didn't fix the problem.